# Add field in checkout in Prestashop 1.7 and handle value

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I create my own module for Prestashop 1.7. For PS 1.6 version it's done. PS 1.7 works a little different ;)
I have problem to handle value from this new field. Just to get this field value.

I would like to add new additional input form field in checkout process - in delivery section or in the last step - payment section. No matter which of this two places.

My modules is ready in general module standard parts.
I can add new field on frontend on this two steps using hook DisplayAfterCarrier or DisplayPaymentByBinaries.
Using hookHeader and addJS, I moved this new input (with label) html code above submit button using prependTo javascript function.

I have:

a) Added in two database tables (ps_cart and ps_orders) columns for value from this new field.

b) I have ovverrided by module classes Cart and Order to handle this new variable. Which works for PS 1.6. Public definition of this new variable.

c) In module main php file code to present new field (in simplification):

```
public function hookDisplayAfterCarrier($params){
  $newFieldHtml='
  <div id="newFieldContainerID">
    <input type="text" id="myNewFieldName" name="myNewFieldName" value="1" />
    <label for="myNewFieldName">Test label for new extra form field. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</label>
  </div>';
  return $newFieldHtml;
}
```

d) How I move field above submit button.
In module main php file:

```
public function hookHeader($params){
  if(isset($this->context->controller->php_self) && $this->context->controller->php_self=='order'){ //to add JS only at cart site
    $this->context->controller->addJS(($this->_path).'views/js/myModuleName.js');
  }
}
```

And this is JS file (myModuleName.js):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#newFieldContainerID').prependTo('#delivery');
    });
});
```

e) I tried te get this value using this hooks:
**ActionCarrierProcess**; 
**ActionCartSave**; 
**ActionValidateOrder**.

Without success. Tools::getValue('myNewFieldName') also does not work.
I have this variable in cart and order objects in $params but always with "0" value (I set this field type as bool and validation for this field in PS as self::TYPE_BOOL).

**How to handle this new value?** How to get it to do anything with it? Anything - for example write to txt file just for debug. If I will have this value - I can save it in cart and order objects, save it to database.

Finally I would like to save this value. But I can't receive, handle it, just to get it. Problem is only in Prestashop 1.7 version.

Comment: lirtosiast, (d) is not a question. It's description how I made this ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with no hook, but overriding classes CheckoutDeliveryStep and CheckoutSession. I mean, I did hookDisplayAfterCarrier (or hookDisplayBeforeCarrier) and hookHeader the same way as you, but no hook is needed to receive and save the custom field. Instead it is needed to override CheckoutDeliveryStep and CheckoutSession. It works fine in PrestaShop 1.7.7.4, I show you the code:

**CheckoutDeliveryStep**

```
class CheckoutDeliveryStep extends CheckoutDeliveryStepCore
{
    public function handleRequest(array $requestParams = [])
    {
        if (isset($requestParams['custom_field'])) {
            $this->getCheckoutSession()->setCustomField($requestParams['custom_field']);
        }

        parent::handleRequest($requestParams);
    }

    public function render(array $extraParams = [])
    {
        $extraParams['custom_field'] = $this->getCheckoutSession()->getCustomField();

        return parent::render($extraParams);
    }
}
```

**CheckoutSession**

```
class CheckoutSession extends CheckoutSessionCore
{
    public function setCustomField($custom_field)
    {
        $this->context->cart->custom_field = $custom_field;

        return $this->context->cart->save();
    }

    public function getCustomField()
    {
        return $this->context->cart->custom_field;
    }
}
```

And don't forget to pass your custom_field value from cart to order. You can do it in createOrderFromCart() method from PaymentModule class (overriding).

I guess this info is enough to get the solution working. Regards.